# Repeating a div on button press in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am following a tutorial here: https://fourtonfish.com/blog/2014-01-dynamically-add-directives-in-angularjs-no-jquery/

to try and append information to a div when a button is pressed. I have got the button added to my home page, however when I click it I receive:

```
angular.js:14324 TypeError: element.bind is not a function
```

I'd love some advice on how to correct this, and potentially even a better approach if there is one. I feel like using element.bind is a jquery approach and there is probably a nicer way to do this with Angular?

main.html

```
<div id ="fullForm" ng-controller="MainCtrl" >                
    <button-add></button-add>
    <div id="test">test</div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name jsongeneratorApp.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the jsongeneratorApp
 */
angular.module('jsongeneratorApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

  .directive('buttonAdd',function(){
    return{
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'scripts/directives/addbutton.html'
  }
})

.directive('addfields',function($compile){
  console.log("directive called.");
  return function(element,attrs){
    element.bind("click",function(){
      angular.element(document.getElementById('test')).append($compile("<div>Test</div>"))
    })
  }
})
```

addbutton.html

```
<div class="row rowmargin">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <button addfields class="btn"> Add New Variable</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This tutorial probably uses an older version of angular. Instead of `element.bind` use `element.on`. See [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) where you can see that `bind` is deprecated

Comment: element.on("click",function()... produces the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element is the second parameter, not the first one. The first one is the `$scope` object of the directive.

It might be possible that you were confused with the dependency injection of angular, but the `link` function of a directive doesn't work with dependency injection.

If you add the scope parameter in the signature it will work:

```
// You missed the first parameter 'scope'
return function(scope, element, attrs){
    element.on("click",function(){
        $compile("<div>Test</div>")(scope, function(compiled){
            // callback
           angular.element(document.getElementById('test')).append(compiled);
        });
    });
}
```

Please also note that the `bind` function [is deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), so you should use `on` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Adding scope leads to the error:
Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'scope' is required which I find a little confusing. Also how did you know scope needed to be added? Is there a way for me to inspect the function or does it just come with experience?

Comment: Yes that is because the `$compile` service expects a scope to compile the html: `$compile("<div>Test</div>")(scope)`

Comment: So this works now..thank you very much! However I am a little confused how you figured out it needed scope and I have also never seen the (scope) syntax added to the end of a function before. Would you be able to explain a little?

Comment: You can read [in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) that the `$compile(..)` function returns another function, which in return expects a `scope` object as first parameter